# Validation on optional Parameter using class-validator in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I want to apply validation on request payload like, there is field name with string type. But name is not compulsory field but if it exist it must execute `@IsNotEmpty()`

I tried something like this
`@IsNotEmpty() name?: string` // it not considering `?` optional constraint

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use the `@IsOptional()` validator:

> Checks if given value is empty (`=== null`, `=== undefined`) and if so, ignores all the validators on the property.

Comment: Then why null values were not filtered by class-validator while I configure class-validator to do whitelist for me. I mean I expect to have no null/undefined value for any defined property, however I do have. And it was an error prone behavior in my case.

Answer (score 35):

[class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) has an `@IsOptional()` validator that you can add on along with any other validators you defined like so:

```js
@IsOptional() @IsNotEmpty() name: string;
```

The decorators are commutative so validation doesn't depend on the order of the validators. If the need to validate depends on something other than presence, you can use [`@ValidateIf()`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) which takes a function argument.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [@ValidateIf](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) conditional validation, this will run other validation if the function return `true`

examle : in this case if `o.otherProperty === 'value'` euqal `true` then the `@IsNotEmpty` will run otherwise it will not run

```
export class Post {
  otherProperty: string;

  @ValidateIf(o => o.otherProperty === 'value')
  @IsNotEmpty()
  example: string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I dislike the functionality of `IsOptional()` as it will allow null values on fields where you havent specified null in the DTO. This means you can inadvertently allow non nullable fields to be nulled.

I created a custom decorator that allows a field to be undefined, but wont let it pass validation as null.

```
import { IsOptional, ValidateIf, ValidationOptions } from 'class-validator'

export function IsOptionalNonNullable(data?: {
  nullable: boolean
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
}) {
  const { nullable = false, validationOptions = undefined } = data || {}

  if (nullable) {
    // IsOptional allows null
    return IsOptional(validationOptions)
  }

  return ValidateIf((ob: any, v: any) => {
    return v !== undefined
  }, validationOptions)
}

// Example usage 
export class SomeUpdateDTO {
  @IsInt()
  // Param can be undefined, but not null 
  @IsOptionalNonNullable()
  nbOfViews?: number
}

// Example of why IsOptional is a problem
export class SomeOtherUpdateDTO {
  @IsInt()
  @IsOptional()
  // Null is not specified, but IsOptional will allow it! 
  // Could end up nulling a required field in the db
  nbOfViews?: number
}
```

Comment: well, that's a nice one

Comment: Hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

Kim's answer is great. If you want to apply this behavior to all of your optional fields, you can also use `skipMissingProperties: true` with your validation pipe(s).

Comment: Could you give an example on where to put this property in the pipes? Thanks

Comment: You can apply a validation pipe globally and pass this config as a option to the pipe's constructor. See the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe).